# error in <ratio> and <memory> after upgrading from vs2013 to vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mutex, c++-chrono

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 and now I get a syntax error in  from standard library.

This is the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ratio(220): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<' 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ratio(221): error C2226: syntax error: unexpected type 'std::integral_constant<_Ty,_Val>::type' 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ratio(221): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ratio(221): error C2059: syntax error: ','
```

This is where it happens:

```
template<class _R1,
    class _R2,
    bool _Sfinae>
    struct _Ratio_multiply_sfinae<_R1, _R2, _Sfinae, void_t<
        typename _Ratio_multiply<_R1, _R2>::_Num::type,
        typename _Ratio_multiply<_R1, _R2>::_Den::type>>
    {   // typename ratio<>::type is unnecessary here
    typedef ratio<
        _Ratio_multiply<_R1, _R2>::_Num::value,
        _Ratio_multiply<_R1, _R2>::_Den::value> type;
    };
```

My guess is that somehow the compiler thinks `>>` is an operator, but I can't edit it to `> >` for testing purposes.

I haven't included `<ratio>` but I think it is used for `<chrono>` and therefore `<mutex>`.

Update:

I just realized that during compilation, InteliSense complains about that place, but before and after compiling it doesn't complain about it. Somehow it seems the compiler setting have been changed, but how I don't know. The other question is why did it work with vs2013.

Comment: Does this happen with a new, clean project (ie just system header files and main)?  If it does not I would suspect a #define in your project is affecting the system header files.

Comment: @RichardCritten not it is not a clean project. A clean project would not be an option for me right now. Do you know what sort of define could cause this issue so I can narrow my search?

Comment: Do you use precompiled header? Did you try to clean and rebuild all?

Comment: @manni66 Yes rebuilding didn't help either.

Comment: Any #define starting with a `_` would be my 1st place to start.  Also why can't you create a new clean (temporary) project and just include the system header file(s) and compile the project (this is to check for inadvertent changes to the system header files)?

Comment: I know it is old topic. But did you solve your issue?

Comment: some problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard changed between C++03 and C++11 to address the issue you mentioned about "> >" vs ">>"

You might need to switch compiler versions.

Comment: My `Platform Toolset` is set to `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)` isn't that already enough?

Comment: You'd think so, but since your reinstall it's possible there are other flags determining how the compiler sees your code. Also you should make sure that's actually the problem. Why can you not add the space and try compiling?

Comment: It is a readonly file. when I change it and try to save it asks to save as, and that wouldn't help me.

Comment: Make another file that's a copy and try using it.

Comment: How can I use it when it is not included by me. This is something that is included deep inside various standard library headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic. But I recently faced a very similar issue. The root cause was that somewhere in the code there was a define like

```
#define void_t void
```

which provoked the compiler errors. Turning it to typedef helped.

As you can see `void_t` is used in the definition of `_Ratio_multiply_sfinae` and is also defined in the `<ratio>` as a templated structure. The define above messed up everything.